# Find if specflow step starts with And or But

Tags: specflow

Is there a way to retrieve if a Specflow scenario step starts with **And** or **But** instead of the Given/When/Then ? I want to write the steps into a text.

Eg:

```
Given this is a step
And this is another one
When I do something
Then something happen
But something else dont
```

Is the And/But stored anywhere that I can retrieve?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need this information? I never had to make a step implementation dependent on And/But.

Comment: I'm trying to store the steps that were executed in a text file, like a small log. Currently, it registers like(considering the example I gave):

Given this is a step/Given this is another one/When I do something/Then something happen/Then something else dont

Again, this is NOT a problem, but it would be nice to log in the same way they were written though

Comment: I understand. Than my answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that it this information is available in the StepInfo (https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow/StepInfo.cs).

```
[Binding]
public class Binding
{ 
    private ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

    public Binding(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    [AfterStep()]
    public void AfterStepHook()
    {
        var stepText = _scenarioContext.ScenarioStepContext.StepInfo.Text;
    }
}
```

Code written without compiling/running.

Comment: Tried that, the Text property returns the step without any keyword and the StepDeifinitionType property returns either Given, When or Then only